# Proof of a convergent series using the limit of another series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this series:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{a_n}} $$

Where $a_n$ is a convergent sequence that tends to $2$, how can I prove that my series above converges?

I first thought to use the "p-test" however surely this would not work as $a_n$ could go from say $1.8, 1.9, 1.99, 1.999 ... 2$ so it is not a constant p the whole time. Can anyone give me a pointer? Thank you!

Comment: For large values of $n$, $a_n$ is close to $2$, i.e. for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\ge1$ such that $2-\varepsilon<a_n<2+\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the convergence of the sequence, there exists an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that when $n>M$, we have $a_n\in(1.5,2.5)$. So, for $n>M$, $n^{a_n}>n^{1.5}$, and $0<\dfrac{1}{n^{a_n}}<\dfrac{1}{n^{1.5}}$. Now, what can you say about
$$\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a_n}} $$

Comment: For all $a_n$ in the interval the series converges, by the p test so the whole series converges?

Comment: @JamesO'dare Are you familiar with the comparison test?

Comment: Yes, so since $0$ "converges and so does $\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$ then my sequence must also converge?

Comment: @JamesO'dare We have a series here. $\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}1/n^{1.5}$ converges by the p-test. Then, by the comparison test, the series I wrote at the end converges. Since removing a finite number of terms doesn't affect convergence, the original series converges as well.

Comment: Got it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For large $n,$ $a_n > 3/2.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial thought to use the p-test will work, but with a little set-up required.

Since $a_n \to 2$, given any arbitrary $y<2$ it can be shown that there are at most finitely many terms in the sequence that are less than $y$.

Choose $y=1$, and let $N$ denote the number of terms in the sequence less than $1$. More explicitly, $$N:= \text{card}\{a_n : a_n <= 1\} < \infty$$

What can you say about this subsequence $a_{N+1}, \dots$?

Given two terms in this subsequence, say $a_{N+j}, a_{N+k}$, suppose that one is greater than the other. What happens to the term $\frac{1}{n^{a_n}}$? *Hint: Comparison test*

Comment: Thank you! Really good explanation